# Transfering data from SQL to Access using C#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

For my current project in c# I need to transfer data from a SQL-Database to an Access-Database. For now I load the data into a DataSet using a SqlDataAdapter. After that I loop through the entries and insert them into the Access-DB using OleDb:

```
// Load data from SQL
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select goes here", sqlConnection);
adapter.Fill(ds);

// Prepare the Insert Command
oleDBCommand = "Insert into...";
oleDBCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter(...));

// Insert every row from the DataSet
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    // Update Parameters and Execute
    oleDBCommand.Parameters[0].Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0];
    oleDBCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This approach works fine, however it feels clumsy and slow. So I was wondering if there is another better way to transfer data from one DB to another.

Comment: You're going from SQL to Access (which isn't supported anymore)... it's maybe a good thing that it feels clumsy and slow ;)

Comment: What do you mean that it feels clumsy?

Comment: It feels as if there has to be a better solution than just loop through every row and call an insert Statement :s

Comment: @Nathan: what does the parenthetical "isn't supported anymore" mean? Access is certainly supported, as is interoperation with SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use SqlDataReader:
   SqlDataReader runs faster than SqlDataAdapter
2. Use Transaction:
   use a transaction and bind each command to this transaction. after finishing the insert commands, commit the transaction, which may run faster.

Comment: Thank you. It was helpful and I'll go with it as an answer, although it wasn't exactly what I was looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Another idea:
If it's always the same Access database and you import your data always from the same table(s), you can [link the SQL Server tables in Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-or-link-to-sql-server-data-HA010200494.aspx#BM2) once.

If a SQL Server table is linked, you can use it in the MDB just like a local table.
Then, you can just insert directly from the linked table into the local table by running this query via OleDB in the Access database:

```
insert into LocalAccessTable (Column1, Column2)
select Column1, Column2
from LinkedSqlServerTable
```